# Coin is thrown until one side falls three times in a row

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

Im new to programing and having problem with one task:

> Coin is thrown until one side falls three times in a row

```
int throwing = 0;

int tail=0;
int head=0;
int counter= 0;
Random rnd = new Random();

do
{
    throwing = rnd.Next(1, 3);
    Console.WriteLine(bacanje);
    counter++;

    if (throwing == 1)
    {
        tail++;
    }
    else if (throwing == 2)
    {
        head++;
    }

} while (tail != 3 && head!= 3);
```

So my problem is that it dosent want to be 3 times in row, program exsit when results are like: head, head, tail, head. And it should be: head, head, head.

Not sure what to change in code, if anyone have some suggestion I would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: As a sidenote, while what you did is correct, normally in c# you "accept" that the first number is 0 and you live with it... `rnd.Next(2)` and then `if (throwing == 0) {} else {}` (no need for the second `if`, the `else` is enough... as the latins said *tertium non datur*, there is no third possible result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never reset the counter for the other if the throw changes, you can simply just reset the other to 0

```
if (throwing == 1)
{
    tail++;
    head = 0;
}
else if (throwing == 2)
{
    head++;
    tail = 0;
}
```

Comment: *while((tail + head) != 3);* don't like much this micro optimization, that doesn't make the code clearer and probably doesn't speed it up.